# FontAwesome Kit loads all versions

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

I have noticed that loading FontAvesome as a kit

`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3052a6a4eb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

will force to load all subversions for version 5 (about 14 different) which makes a website noticeable slow.

Is there any way just to let it load particular version (or versions) not all 14?

Comment: Are you using FA pro or free ?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/troubleshooting#subset

Comment: @Nicolas I'm using free version. Kit generated via their site

Comment: @j08691 You mean to load directly like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.1/css/all.css">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue without a fix so far.
Look here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15167